# USB Switchboard of some kind - Do they exist?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, switch, headset

I've come into a situation where I will have to be using two different computers (side by side) constantly.  Now, there isn't enough space to keep two keyboards, two mice, and two headsets.  After considering the situation I remembered the old switchboard systems that could do this.  The problem is, this was 10 years ago and this is USB, not PS/2.  All of my devices are wireless so they have to have USB receivers.

**What I imagine would work:**

A switchboard that fakes the USB still being there.  It would be nearly impossible to work with it if I had to wait for all of my devices to switch over and be recognized by the computer.  It would have to somehow seamlessly switch over.

Anyways, any suggestions for the situation or links to something that would give me the result I need are appreciated.

Comment: I find it far more convenient to remote-desktop into the second computer, and simply alt-tab between the local computer and the remote one than to switch the KVM, or buy a KVM switch. Why bother?

Comment: @DalexL: you did not mention OS:es here, since you were looking for a

Comment: hardware solution. But a software solution might give you cut-and-paste between computers, and also quite a lot fewer cables.

Comment: @Warren: That's probably ideal for most situations, but sometimes you want to work directly on the computer not through a remote desktop. RDP/VNC/etc. do have their limitations. For things like gaming or any kind of DCC, you'd want to take advantage of the local hardware. Even on a relatively robust system, you can still experience some lag in input vs. redrawing of the display when, say, digital painting. A remote desktop is likely to make things much worse. Though this might be a corner case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they make KVM switches that emulate USB HID devices, and can switch audio.

Depending on your specific needs, something like this may work for you:  http://www.dlink.com/products/?pid=511

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen synergy? It's a software solution that sounds like exactly what you want, plus more! http://synergy-foss.org/

Comment: Nifty. I had not heard of this. I usually just use VNC or RemoteDesktop.

Comment: Does it have reasonable performance?

Comment: I've never had any issues with performance. It also lets you share the clipboard, and copy files from one machine to the other. It's way faster than VNC, but requires you to have two monitors.